# How to select random value in an associate array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a data(Associate array) that I got from mysql database which looks like this

```
$data=[
    ["id"=>"1", "words"=>"words 1"],
    ["id"=>"2", "words"=>"words 2"],
    ["id"=>"3", "words"=>"words 3"],
    ["id"=>"4", "words"=>"words 4"],
    ["id"=>"5", "words"=>"words 5"],
    ["id"=>"6", "words"=>"words 6"],
    ["id"=>"7", "words"=>"words 7"],
    ["id"=>"8", "words"=>"words 8"],
    ["id"=>"9", "words"=>"words 9"],
    ["id"=>"10", "words"=>"words 10"]
];
```

Now I want to form a new array that contains only 3 random arrays from this array (`$data`) but i cant do it, the function i am using is not working

Below is my code

```
$count="3";
$rand = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(array_rand($array, $count)))
```

I want the new array to look like this

```
$new_data=[
    ["id"=>"1", "words"=>"words 1"],
    ["id"=>"2", "words"=>"words 2"],
    ["id"=>"3", "words"=>"words 3"]
];
```

in which the arrays are selected at random not just `1, 2, 3`.

Please how can i achieve this, what am i doing that is wrong

Comment: This looks like it should work just fine other than the mismatched variable names (`$data` vs `$array`). What do you mean by "not working"? What is it doing that you don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually **your source data works exactly as you request** -- Have you just made a typo with `$data` array and the reference value in $rand being *`$array`* when it should be `$data`?

---

Try using array shuffle and then slice the array to only be X number long. Note with this method that the original outer array keys (numeric) will not be preserved, whereas with your original working version they are preserved.

```
$count = 3; // how many array rows do you want to keep?
$newData = $data; // source array.
shuffle($newData);  // reorder the array. 
$newData = array_slice($newData,0,$count); // cut off after $count elements.
```

> Please note that PHP `shuffle` is not suitable for any cryptographic randomness.

[PHP `shuffle()` Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

[PHP `array_slice()` Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Yes, chunk does virtually the same thing but is more angled for multiple chunks, whereas `array_slice`  is only for getting one chunk from the source data. But both functions can work here.